# Netbeans 8.2 Java multi-line comment add user/date-time with keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, comments, netbeans-8

In Netbeans 8.2, is it possible to automatically fill user and date-time with a keyboard shortcut? Or configurable text?

I want to add user, date-time, etc. to Java block comments with a keyboard shortcut. I looked in Templates and examples online but only found things for at file creation or single Macros (date-time macro).

I can add an example if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trivial to set a keyboard shortcut to insert date/time in NetBeans, but I think you may be out of luck on setting a shortcut for the user.

**Shortcut for date/time**

For date/time all you need to do is define a shortcut for the existing **Action** named **Insert Current Date and Time**:

- Select **Tools -> Options** then click the **Keymap** icon. Locate the action named **Insert Current Date and Time** in the **Actions** column, and select that line so that the background is blue.
- Click the button on that line with the three dots and select **Edit...** from the drop down menu. The cursor will be positioned in the **Shortcut** column on that line. Now enter a keyboard shortcut that you would like to use to enter the date and time. I chose **Ctrl+D**.
- Click the **OK** button to close the **Options** window.
- Now position the mouse cursor anywhere in a ***.java** file and press **Ctlr+D** (or whatever shortcut you chose), and the current date/time will be inserted with a format like this: **1/20/18 12:23 AM**.

**Shortcut for user**

I couldn't get this to work, but here is some relevant background information in case it helps you to have better luck.

- First you need to set the value of the template variable named **${user}**. I don't know how this works on Linux, but on Windows its default value seems to be your Windows user ID, which may or may not be what you want. A simple way to see the value of **${user}** is to create a new class and look at the value for **@author** in the block comment above the class name.
- If you  want to change its value open the **Template Manager** window using **Tools -> Templates** and click the **Settings** button. A file named **User.properties** will be opened. The last line should start with **#user=**. Uncomment that line by removing the **#** and set whatever value you want for **user**, such as **John Doe (john.doe@myco.com)** and save the file.
- Create another new class and you should see the updated value for **${user}** being used.
- Now for the final step that didn't work for me. Select **File -> Option**, click the **Editor** icon and then select the **Code Templates** tag. Click the **New** button. In the **New Code Template** window enter an abbreviation to be used to insert the user (e.g. **usr** ) and click **OK**. In the **Expanded Text** field enter the value **${user}**, click the **Contexts** tab and check the **CLASS** box, click **Apply** and then click **OK** to close the **Options** window.
- Within the source of a Java class enter the abbreviation you just specified (e.g. **usr** ) and press the **TAB** key. I was expecting to see the value of **${user}** template variable inserted, but instead I only got **user**. Maybe template variables only get expanded when using File Templates, and not when using Code Templates? Or maybe it's a bug, or I have missed a step in the process.

Comment: Thanks for this really thorough answer; this is basically what has to be done. As you suggest, I think template variables are nott expanded in Code Templates. I may bring this up as an issue/feature request soon. I ended up doing the following: made a custom code template (would have to do per language) that has my user (hard-coded, but am only user on my machine using my Netbeans), and has two variable fields for Date and a field for our internal issue tracking ID. I use ${date} and ${issid} to make these variables. The date is not auto resolved, but I can type it out quickly by tabbing